# AWS URL REDIRECTION ISSUE

Tags: amazon-web-services

is there any service in aws to redirect one url to Another url. route 53 is used for the domain name redirection. may i know any particular service is there for the url redirection. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately there is no service as you say You can use Route 53 as it is full fledged DNS Service.

If you could explain what use case is maybe we could help out more.

Thanks